# Row duplicating in a table in JavaScript when I search again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in JavaScript and PHP, I just want to search for data in a table, but doing so, when I click again in the search button its recall again the PHP file responsible for the SQL request and displays the data under the previous ons again and again do you have any solution to avoid that. Here is my code.

```
 function postselect() {
   var _type = $('#typeid').val();
   var _pression = $('#pressionid').val();
   var _code = $('input[name="code"]').val();
   var _designiation = $('input[name="designiation"]').val();
   var _diametre = $('input[name="diametre"]').val();
   var _epaisseur = $('input[name="epaisseur"]').val();
   var _prix = $('input[name="prix"]').val();
   var _etat = $('input[name="etat"]').val();

   // code ici avant   mising pour ne pas avoir de multiple  
   $.post('select.php', {
       posttype: _type,
       postpression: _pression,
       postcode: _code,
       postdesigniation: _designiation,
       postdiametre: _diametre,
       postepaisseur: _epaisseur,
       postprix: _prix,
       postetat: _etat
     }, function(data) {
       $('tbody').append(data);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are **append**ing the data, it appends. Before you append data, clear it using:

```
$('tbody').html("").append(data);
```

The alternate is to use `.empty()`.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, for some reason, the OP had `.html(data)`. Not sure why it didn't work. Check out the revision?

Comment: I never even saw the original version. That should have worked.

Comment: Yea, that's why I gave this answer. Else why would I?

Comment: `.html(data)` was on a different element (`.table` instead of `tbody`) and was commented out. The actual code had `.append()`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah okay... :)

Answer (score 0):

you are appending items on every click without removing the previous elements.

you can try this:

from:

```
function(data) {
   $('tbody').append(data);
});
```

to:

```
function(data) {
   $('tbody').empty();
   $('tbody').append(data);
});
```

Comment: `empty` + `append` = `html`

Comment: I know that, this is just a simple alternative to the ops question. anyway, thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace the contents of the element, not add to it, use `.html()`:

```
$('tbody').html(data);
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason, the OP had `.html(data)`. Not sure why it didn't work. Check out the revision?

Comment: It was commented out, so it wasn't relevant.